# Regular Expression to make a chain of pairs of words, some with commas between, some without

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to work out a regex which does a chaining system of pairs of words, but differently if words have only spaces between them or if they have comma spaces between them.

So if I had the following:

```
fruit apples red, oranges orange, bananas yellow
```

What would happen is I'd get pairs of words beside each other if there is a space, otherwise if there is a comma, I'd get a pair returning back to the original word.

The results of this regex (or perhaps two regexes, one for space and one for comma space) would be:

```
[(fruit, apples),
 (apples, red),
 (fruit, oranges),
 (oranges, orange),
 (fruit, bananas),
 (bananas, yellow)]
```

Or, for the spaces:

```
[(fruit, apples),
 (apples, red),
 (oranges, orange),
 (bananas, yellow)]
```

And, for the comma spaces:

```
[(fruit, oranges),
 (fruit, bananas)]
```

If either a single solution or two separate solutions is easy for any of you to work out, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm having a bit of trouble with all these regular expressions but I'm trying to ask my questions in pieces so I can learn the core steps and combine it so at least I feel like I'm doing something.

p.s. I'm doing this in python, hence the list of tuples.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a regex? String splitting seems to work in the sample case.

```
s = 'fruit apples red, oranges orange, bananas yellow'
classification, examples = s.split(' ', 1)
examples = [x.split() for x in examples.split(', ')]
result = []
for example in examples:
    result.append((classification, example[0]))
    result.append(tuple(example))

>>> result
[('fruit', 'apples'), ('apples', 'red'), ('fruit', 'oranges'), ('oranges', 'orange'), ('fruit', 'bananas'), ('bananas', 'yellow')]
```

Comment: well, I hope to make the whole thing a bit more complex and combine it with another regex that I'm working on which will tag each word like #fruit ##apples for example. Sometimes, there might be two words like ##apple juice. Perhaps I could work your approach in and then utilize the regex within each..

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need regex in this case ! what you need is extract the `fruit` name from your string and then create a new one !

```
>>> name=s.split()[0]
>>> name
'fruit'
```

create new string :

```
>>> new=' '.join(s.split()[1:])
>>> new
'apples red, oranges orange, bananas yellow'
>>> new_s=new.split(',')
['apples red', ' oranges orange', ' bananas yellow']
```

then you can create your proper tuples with `name` and `new`

```
>>> z= zip(*[i.split() for i in new_s])
[('apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'), ('red', 'orange', 'yellow')]

>>>t1= [(name,i) for i in z[0]]
[('fruit', 'apples'), ('fruit', 'oranges'), ('fruit', 'bananas')]
```

and you can have another tuples then append them together:

```
>>>t2= [tuple(i.split()) for i in new_s]
[('apples', 'red'), ('oranges', 'orange'), ('bananas', 'yellow')]

>>> t1+t2
[('fruit', 'apples'), ('fruit', 'oranges'), ('fruit', 'bananas'), ('apples', 'red'), ('oranges', 'orange'), ('bananas', 'yellow')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((\w+)\s*\w+)
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/38

i guess this way you can do it.

1)From your original string remove first word ie `fruit`.

2)Then apply the regex.Grab the captures.

3)Then append your first word, i.e`fruit` to all single elements.